# Any tips on where to start learning quantum computing?

Tags: resource-request

I am very interested in this field right now, due to the quantum advantage 
and would like some helpful nudges in the right direction i.e. where should I start from.

P.S: I have some background in software engineering and subpar knowledge in math and physics.

Comment: thanx and sorry bout that

Comment: No problem. You are new in the site so there is no issue in comitting mistakes. I just did it to keep the integrity of the site. Do not worry and continue learning how this SE works!